# Django, unique email, error on update profile

Tags: django, email, unique, edit, profile

In my app I got the following issue. During the registration, the email address has to be unique by using a custom *clean_edit* method. So in **update_profile** form, i'm using the same function(*clean_edit*) to check if the email address entered is unique. If the user doesn't change his email address(and change just his first name) then he is getting an error that says "This email is used by another user". This happens because in the update profile form, the placeholder for email address has the email address of the current user. So when click submit, the app tried to update his email address too, but returns error that the email is already used. Below you can find clean_email of UpdateProfile class.

```
def clean_email(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
    email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
    if User.objects.filter(email=email).exclude(username=username).exclude(email=email).count():
            raise forms.ValidationError('This email address is already in use. '
                                        'Please supply a different email address.')
    return email
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a question here but I do see a problem with this code. You can't access other fields inside a clean_foo method because they might not be available yet. If you're going to use multiple fields during validation (as you do here), override the clean method instead.

However, it does appear that you don't need the username. I would recommend this check instead:

```
if User.objects.filter(email__iexact=email).count() > 0:
        raise forms.ValidationError('This email address is already in use. '
                                    'Please supply a different email address.')
```

The email__iexact is a case-insensitive compare.

Comment: The thing is that I got this code from a tutorial. It is supposed to check that the email address isn't used by another member. So since I'm new to Django and python, I don't totally get why it uses **excludes**.
In my case, I only want to check if the email address isn't used by another member, but it's ok to be used by the logged in user. Any ideas on this one?

Comment: With this code , if I process the form(without changing the email address), I'm getting the error that this email address is already in use. A bit weird isn't it?